VS2022 Test Explorer isn't showing tests written with GTest in a CMake project
I spent most of the day yesterday trying to get a GTest CMake project to work in VS2022. Everything builds and compiles but test explorer won't show any tests. Hitting Run All causes it to sit in an infinite loop not progressing. I've produced a minimal repro here https://github.com/GingerbreadFred/GoogleTestRepro/.
The CMakeLists for the project is below
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(HelloWorldTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/f8d7d77c06936315286eb55f8de22cd23c188571.zip
)

set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

enable_testing()

add_executable(HelloWorld 
    src/HelloWorld.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(HelloWorld GTest::gtest_main)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(HelloWorld)

And HelloWorld.cpp
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(HelloWorld, Test)
{
    int i = 0;
    EXPECT_EQ(0, i);
}

The tests work if I do Test -> Run CTests but test explorer is oblivious. I can't see anything in the output window that would suggest what the problem is. To be honest I'm stumped.

The observed behavior seems to be caused by the incorrect test executable, which doesn't allow to request list of tests. Like in that recent question (make sure to read its self-answer). If you think that your test executable is correctly written, then add its code (src/HelloWorld.cpp) into the question post (as [mcve]).

I have added the contents of HelloWorld.cpp to the question, as you can see it's fairly minimal. I'm not sure that the issue is that the test executable is incorrect. This program does generate a valid executable that I can manually run and generate a test list from
.\HelloWorld.exe --gtest_list_tests
Running main() from C:\Work\Test\GTestTest\out\build\x64-Debug_deps\googletest-src\googletest\src\gtest_main.cc
HelloWorld.
Test

This actually turned out to be a visual studio configuration issue. There appears to be a conflict with CTest integration in Visual Studio and the Unreal Engine Test Adapter. Uninstalling the Unreal Engine Test Adapter has made everything work. I'll open an issue with the Visual Studio team.

The Test Explorer in Visual Studio doesn't recognize test sites with arbitrary names. Test suits must have "Test" suffix in their names.
TEST(HelloWorldTest, Test)
{
    int i = 0;
    EXPECT_EQ(0, i);
}


I have figured this out it appeared to be a Visual Studio issue (see my answer). Note that this statement is incorrect I now have a working example with the following test name
TEST(Hello, World)
{
int i = 0;
EXPECT_EQ(0, i);
}
